# CoffeeScript variable scope

Tags: coffeescript

Is there any way to declare a variable at "file" scope (which will be closured by CS), without initializing it? A contrived example:

```
init = ->
  counter = 0

inc = ->
  counter += 1
```

This won't work, because you need to declare "counter". Adding "counter = 0" to the top would make it work, but the "= 0" is unnecessary. (A more realistic example would involve something that accesses the DOM on page load - there's no way to correctly initialize it in "file" scope.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll have to define it on the outer scope, as you mentioned.

```
counter = null
init = ->
  counter = 0
inc = ->
  counter += 1
```

Comment: +1. Shorthands have been proposed, but jashkenas is a firm believer in the `= null` syntax.

Comment: I haven't seen that, but I guess the rationale is to keep the keyword count low.

Answer (score 4):

If your functions where part of an object you could use @counter, like this:

```
obj = 
  init: ->
    @counter = 0
  inc: ->
    @counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can say `var counter;` with backticks and that is passed literally through to the generated javascript.

When you have a problem like this, look at the generated javascript.  It will be extremely clear that the variable scope is lexically limited to the function.

Looking at the generated javascript is often a good way to understand what the behavior of coffeescript constructs is.